# Stylesheets, images and javascript are not loading on heroku server in rails4

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

Hello I have included following in my gemfile

```
group :production, :staging do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

and inmy stylesheets i have included images as mytest.css.scss

```
.abc{background: image-url('/assets/mobile/phone.png');}
```

in production.rb

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.assets.compile = true
```

and in herokurun bash  I have rake assets:precompile also but still its not loading images , stylesheets and javascripts. Please guide me how to solve this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try one of these:

```
background-image: image-url("logo.png")

background-image: asset-url("logo.png", image)

background-image: asset-url($asset, $asset-type)

background-image: asset-data-url("logo.png")
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, Heroku takes time to recognize new assets - we've found that if you restart the dyno after precompilation, it often loads them on refresh: `heroku restart`

You should accompany this with the referenced dynamic helpers (as per `sadaf2605`'s answer:

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/application.js
.element {
   background: asset_url("your_image_url.png");
}
```

The other thing you need to do is precompile for `production` --

`rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`

---

**Debug**

It's tough to see what the issue might be; the main way we debug this is as follows:

1. On push, `right-click` on your app and `view source`
2. In the `console`, you'll probably see a series of `404` (`resource not found`) errors.
3. These errors will denote which files Rails is looking for - look for the [fingerprints](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care-questionmark).

If the app is looking for fingerprinted files, it's a good sign (it means the files you have are incorrect). To resolve this, you should just precompile *before* sending to Heroku:

```
$ rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
$ git add .
$ git commit -a -m "Fix"
$ git push heroku master
```

This will send the right files to Heroku.

If your app is not looking for the fingerprinted files, it means you have to reference them properly in your CSS. I think you already know about this (written above).